# HTML5 Video causes weird glitch in CSS :hover transition, doesn't work well cross-browser

Tags: hover, sprite, html5-video, css-transitions

I've got my main page here:
http://thenozzle.net/

The logo at the top of the page is a sprite, switches between top and bottom to give the glow effect. This is done with css transition and :hover pseudo element.

However, I recently added the 'projekktor' HMTL5 video player. It works really well, but if you start the video, then hover of the logo, it glitches out when you mouse-over.

Also, Google Chrome doesn't play the video served from ea.com
The Battlefield 3 clip. Chrome won't play it, these two things are driving me nuts. COuld they be related? What am I doing wrong?

Projekktor homepage: http://www.projekktor.com/

It performs differently in every browser. Horribly slow in Firefox, but it plays. Perfect in Safari, CHrome it won't play at all, but Safari has the glitchy logo. Any ideas?

Comment: can you make a small video of the glitch and put it somewhere, it seems that for me it works fine

Comment: The glitch is in Safari. Does it play for you in Chrome?

Comment: is this the problem? it is broken in IExplore as well...  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/glitchg.png/

Comment: No, that's just due to my current lack of IE bug fixing. Have you tried in Safari? If you can tell me what browsers you're getting this to play in, I would be appreciative.

Comment: at first I missed the Safari reference (*blush*) but I tried in Opera (looks OK for me), Firefox (no problems at all - not slow or anything) and Explorer

Comment: wait... the video in Firefox wasn't glitchy at all? Excellent! Must be my shitty video card. Now the even stranger problem of the glitch, I'll make a video

Comment: I don't know where to put the video. :/
But it's super strange, it just tweaks out when you mouse over it and jitters around. I know it's caused by the video because it doesn't happen till you hit play and the video loads.

Comment: maybe it is really just issue of your GC

Comment: or maybe the player gets focus in a loop somehow...

Comment: put the vid on youtube, I really want to know the solution :)

Comment: Youtube did nothing. The glitch wasn't there. Could you test video performance in Firefox once more?

Comment: I think it's just the poor performance of javascript, does the menubar run slowly as well?

Comment: no - I mean - make a desktop vid of the glitch you get and upload it on youtube so we can see what it does

Comment: I've got it, is has to do with the presence of the wrapped 'headlink'. If you remove it, no glitch, but no link back to home either. hmmm....

Comment: it wasn't headlink, it was JUST the text-indent property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I removed 1 of the two anchors, and removed the headlink text-indent property from the div, and put it on the single anchor. Weird problem, weird solution. For future reference, don't try to text-indent text that buried more then one level deep, on your rollover it will jump back and forth spiratically.

```
<div title="The Nozzle" id="headerlogo">
    <div title="The Nozzle" id="logo1"></div>
    <a style="text-indent:-9999px" title="The Nozzle" href="http://thenozzle.net/"><div title="The Nozzle" id="logo2"></div>The Nozzle</a>
</div>
```